# SQL, Query into Excel, Setting Criteria/Parameters?

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

I've inherited a workbook that has a query in it, which I believe is run in the server and not in excel (if that sounds right?). It has the criteria in it shown below, I understand the `'0'` means it returns all Sites/Divisions/Products/Accounts etc. 
My question is how to I change the code to just show (say) 5 sites? 151,153,169,201,210
I basically need to make the workbook smaller as it can't handle all the data.

```
        @Site = N'0',

        @Division = N'0',

        @Product = N'0',

        @Account = N'0',
```

Many thanks

(My first time trying to edit/read SQL)

Comment: These are just the parameters. Do you see actual query?

Comment: The command text just states EXEC [Navision Reporting].[dbo].[usp_.        ] Is it possible to just re-write (somehow) the parameter line?

Comment: Depends on what the stored procedure expects as parameters. If it is designed to handle comma separated list of site IDs then yes. Otherwise you will have to modify the procedure as well

Comment: Thanks Yuriy, I think i understand a little more now. I've tried the comma seperaton and it returns an error, saying incorrect syntax. So I assume this means a procedure modification. Which is beyond me and my access rights. Appreciate yourhelp.